# Spark 2.3 dynamic partitionBy not working on S3 AWS EMR 5.13.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, bigdata, amazon-emr

Dynamic partitioning introduced by Spark 2.3 doesn't seem to work on AWS's EMR 5.13.0 when writing to S3

When executing, a temporary directory is created in S3 but it disappears once the process is completed without writing the new data to the final folder structure.

The issue was found when executing a Scala/Spark 2.3 application on EMR 5.13.0.

The configuration is as follows:

```
var spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName(MyClass.getClass.getSimpleName)
  .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","DYNAMIC") // also tried "dynamic"
```

The code that writes to S3:

```
val myDataset : Dataset[MyType] = ...

val w = myDataset
    .coalesce(10)
    .write
    .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
    .option("compression", "snappy")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .partitionBy("col_1","col_2")

w.parquet(s"$destinationPath/" + Constants.MyTypeTableName)
```

With *destinationPath* being a S3 bucket/folder

Anyone else has experienced this issue?

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same issue. Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: unfortunately no.

Comment: OK, thanks for letting me know anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to EMR 5.19 fixes the problem. However my previous answer is incorrect - using the EMRFS S3-optimized Committer has nothing to do with it. The EMRFS S3-optimized Committer is silently skipped when spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode is set to dynamic: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-committer-reqs.html

<s>If you can upgrade to at least EMR 5.19.0, AWS's EMRFS S3-optimized Committer solves these issues.</s>

`--conf spark.sql.parquet.fs.optimized.committer.optimization-enabled=true`

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-s3-optimized-committer.html